# Replaced .css() with .animate() and it's not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a parallax-ish effect when you move your cursor over the header by shifting an image. I got it working with .css() — I included that in the line that's commented out in the code below — but I replaced it with .animate() because I want easing, and the animation isn't working.

```
var width = 50 / $(window).width();
$('header').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    //$('#headerImg img').css('transform', 'translateX(calc(-50% - ' + newvalueX + 'px))');
    $('#headerImg img').animate({
        'transform': 'translateX(calc(-50% - ' + newvalueX + 'px))'
    }, 'slow', function() {
        console.log('check');
    });
});
```

The console.log DOES work, and there are no errors, but the .animate() itself does nothing. I'm thining it must be something really dumb on my part!

Comment: jQuery doesn't understand complicated transforms like that, just regular numbers, so it can't animate it.

Comment: @adeneo I see... :/ I have a second animation for another element; that one looks like: `'backgroundPosition': 'calc(50% + ' + newvalueX + 'px) 0'`. Is that one not working for the same reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use easing with css:

```
#headerImg img{
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

For more information:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Comment: Oh, it's nice to know that that exists. That's for transitions though, right? This isn't a transition. :(

Comment: It can work actually, just add a transition in the css! :) I edited the example to reflect this.